What should I do when I see an incorrect answer?
This is a continuation of a discussion from a comment thread elsewhere.
Here is the basic question.  When I see an incorrect answer, what would you recommend that I do?
I have always assumed that what I should do is downvote an incorrect answer, and (ideally) post a comment explaining why the answer is incorrect, to help readers understand what the error was.  However, apparently in doing so in at least one case, I have managed to hurt one poster's feelings and made him feel like he was under personal attack.  That is not my intent, and I don't want to see that happen.
@Ninefingers has suggested that "the best course of action when you disagree with something is to use your vote (you're entitled to do that) - for minor issues (did you mean XYZ?) comments work, but otherwise propose an alternative solution."  Can anyone elaborate on what this means?  Does this mean: (i) if the answer is incorrect and it is a major error, then downvote, but do not post a comment (and if possible post a correct solution), (ii) if the answer is incorrect and it is a minor error, then downvote and do post a comment?  Is that what the community wants me to do?  If I see a major error, don't comment on it?  And if the person who posted the inaccurate answer asks for an explanation of why they got downvoted, then it's better to just not answer, despite their request?
I'm happy to follow whatever the community norms are.  I'm hoping someone can elaborate on what they are.
Unfortunately, cryptography is a technical subject where there are correct and incorrect answers.  Incorrect answers can put security at risk -- yet incorrect answers can often be quite hard to spot.  It is not uncommon for people to think they have a correct answer, without realizing that their answer is actually incorrect.  The policy I have followed is that if I see an inaccuracy that I feel the question-asker (or other readers) needs to know about, I try to actively point out and correct those errors.  I've assumed that it is important to post a comment explaining the error, because errors can be hard to spot until they are pointed out (and because the voting process doesn't work if only one person is aware of the subtle error in the post but doesn't tell anyone about it).  In addition, if the answerer explicitly asks for comments (as in this case), I try to post them.
However, perhaps what I haven't taken into account is that it is only human to have your feelings hurt if someone tells you that your answer is incorrect.  Perhaps @Ninefingers' message is that it is better to let incorrect answers stand, without trying to correct them -- in the interests of keeping the peace, it's better to stick to just downvoting, without trying to call attention to errors in the comments?  That creating a welcoming and friendly atmosphere is more important than correcting every technical error?  Am I interpreting this feedback correctly?
I'd welcome your thoughts on how the community wants me to handle such situations.  Thank you in advance!

Downvoting wrong answers is what you are supposed to do with your votes. When you downvote, it is considered polite to add a comment explaining why you downvote. Most authors of wrong answers will take the hint and correct their answers. It is unavoidable that a few will react emotionally and may even try to retaliate in a most childish way. C'est la vie. The risks of such an occurrence can be lowered by using diplomatic skills in the comment: in a nutshell, the more negative a comment is, the coldest it should be. Talk like a soviet droid. Because it cannot be a personal attack if it seems to emanate from someone totally devoid of any personality...
There is no requirement that you comment when you downvote. Sometimes it can be predicted, with great accuracy, that the answer's author will never take the hint, and instead will shout at whoever comments on His great answer; in that case, just downvote.
What @Ninefingers was suggesting is that in case the answer you downvote is well beyond any salvation, you can post another competing answer, which hopefully will be upvoted and bubble up higher than the offending post. This is mostly orthogonal to the question of whether you shall comment or not your downvotes.
Editing the offending answer to add a banner, saying that the answer is all wrong, is technically feasible, but much frowned upon; don't do it. Even if well-intentioned, this kind of thing can only escalate into full-scale warfare. That's possibly the most "sacred" thing in the stackexchange network: each author is master of his posts. Third party edits should be typographical only.

Pointing out errors (or asking for clarifications) is what comments are for. In the best case, then the errors are corrected, and the comment can be deleted afterwards. (Feel free to flag such comments as "obsolete" after they are incorporated into the post.)
Contrary to Thomas I think non-typographic edits to an answer are not totally taboo: If the answerer didn't come back for some time, and the problem seems to be easy to fix with an edit (without completely changing the spirit of the answer), go ahead and fix it. (Adding a this answer is wrong banner is not a fix.) If the answer owner reverts such an edit, let it be, don't start an edit war.
That said, the FAQ says explicitely:

Civility is required at all times; rudeness will not be tolerated. Be nice.

Some of your comments could be read as less nice than they could have been, which the authors of the corresponding post could have seen as an attack. (My view might be a bit skewed here, since you are (after me) the user with the most comments, as far as I can tell. I also didn't find any dubious examples just now.) 
So, maybe one way to avoid this problem: Before submitting a comment (especially one pointing out mistakes), read it again, and think if it could be said in a nicer tone.
As said by Thomas, posting an own answer is independent of commenting an existing one. But it is often preferable to adding long comment threads to another answer, if the information in this comments can also be used to directly answer the question instead of only to point out errors.
